# SQLite query doesnt return results

Tags: objective-c, sqlite

Am running the following query from xcode. 
It is however not returning any results. 
I am pretty sure it should return results and can confirm the same by running the same query from sqlite browser. From within xcode however, sqlite3_step returns code 101.
What am i doing wrong here?

```
    NSMutableArray *pages = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    char *query = " \
    drop table if exists tempT; \
    \
    create temporary table tempT \
    as \
    select \
    Page \
    from \
    ( \
     select 1 as Sort, 'Home' as Page \
     union \
     select 2 as Sort, 'Research' as Page \
     union \
     select distinct 3 as Sort, Category as Page from Researches \
     union \
     select 4 as Sort, 'Drafts' as Page \
     union \
     select 5 as Sort, 'Outbox' as Page \
     union \
     select 6 as Sort, 'Download' as Page \
     union \
     select 7 as Sort, 'Settings' as Page \
     union \
     select 8 as Sort, 'Deleted' as Page \
     ) as Sub \
    ORDER BY Sort, Page \
    ; \
     \
    select Page from tempT order by rowid \
    ";
    sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, query, -1, &stmt, nil) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        while (sqlite3_step(stmt) == SQLITE_ROW)
        {
            [pages addObject: [NSString stringWithUTF8String: (char *)sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 0)]];
        }

        sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
    }

    return pages;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sqlite3_prepare_v2` only prepares the first statement, you will have to run the 3 statements separately.

See: http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/prepare.html

> If pzTail is not NULL then *pzTail is made to point to the first byte past the end of the first SQL statement in zSql. These routines only compile the first statement in zSql, so *pzTail is left pointing to what remains uncompiled.